# Topics in Algebra, 2nd Ed, Section 2.5, Problem 10

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be the group of integers under addition, $ H_{n} $ the subgroup consisting of all multiples of a fixed $n$ in $G.$ Determine the index of $ H_{n} $ in $G$ and write out all the right cosets of $ H_{n} $ in $G$.

So, all I know here so far is that we're looking for a number of distinct cosets and $H_{n} = \{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$? I don't know if this is right. I don't even know where to begin here.

Comment: Do you mean to say that $H$ is the subgroup with such $n\in G$?   $nH$ is not a subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are $n$ cosets, namely exactly
$$H_n+0,\ H_n+1,\ \dots,\ H_n+(n-1)$$
where $G$ contains all (negative, zero, positive) integers and $H_n=\{\dots,-4n,-3n,-2n,-n,0,n,2n,3n,4n,\dots\}$.

Then $H_n+1=\{\ldots,-4n+1,\,-3n+1,\,-2n+1,\,-n+1,\,1,\,n+1,\,2n+1,\,3n+1,\dots\}$, and so on.

Comment: OK, so, to interpret this, G = {...-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3...} and Hn = {...-3n,−2n,−n,0,n,2n,3n...} and then we add starting with 0 Hn + 0 is the first right coset, then Hn + 1, Hn + 2, ... Hn + (n-1) until we hit identity, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So the index of $H_n$ in $G$ is $n$. (Note that the usual notation for the additive group of integers is $\Bbb Z$ and $\ n\Bbb Z$ for the subgroup $H_n$.)